# Define a function compute_bill that takes one argument food as input

Tags: python-3.x

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill (food): 
    total = 0  
    for item in food:  
        for key in item:  
            total += item[key]  
    return (total)
```

This is what i have done. But its not working properly.
**Error: compute_bill(['apple']) resulted in a TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str**

Comment: please input the full code, the above code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `total += item[key]` to `prices[key]` and remove `for key in item:`

Comment: If this answer solved your question, click on the check-mark. It will mark the question as solved and give reputation to you and the answerer. There is no obligation to do this.